# direct double quoted text can be inserted into sql database, but single quote to double quote converted string is inserted as empty into the database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a textbox where i can type double quoted words like: hello i am "steve" and i can successfully insert the string into my database after mysqli_real_escape_string

```
<textarea name="description"></textarea>
```

php below:

```
$text_data = $_POST['description']; // hello my name is "steve" 
$final_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn,$text_data);

// the above without removing double quotes can be inserted into the db

but if it is single quotes and I convert to double quotes then it cannot be inserted.

$text_data = $_POST['description']; // hello my name is 'steve'
$final_text = str_replace("'",'"',$text_data);
$final_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn,$text_data);
```

so my questions are:

1. how come it works with double quotes? doesn't it needs to be removed or replaced with "/ something?
2. if the first case: double quotes work fine, then how come the second case when converted from single to double quotes cannot be inserted into the db?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This question should be closed and deleted because there is no actual query shown and the reason could be anything. A some silly mistake most likely

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple things..

First I would do some reading on the differences between the single quote and the double quote's behaviors.  Just so going forward you have a basis for the differences between the two.

Secondly lets look at the logic of your code:

If I replace the single quotes in your code like your code suggest your statement will look like this:

```
"hello my name is "steve""
```

No lets look closly at what happens between " and steve.

```
"hello my name is "  steve ""
```

The reason your query is failing, I believe is because steve is not quoted anymore.

Using prepared statement is really your best solution to the problem.

Hope that helps

UPDATED:

```
$text_data = "hello my name is 'steve'"; 
$final_text = str_replace("'",'\"',$text_data);
```

Comment: thx for your answer , I have updated my question. as you can see I am using $_POST['description'] instead of hard coding the string

Comment: You are saying that the string is not being inserted by the query.  What error are you getting?

Comment: But other strings that do not have quotes are being insereted by your query

Comment: yes other string are being inserted >< that's why im so confused

Comment: Both Farooq Khan and Poonam were trying to illustrate the concept of escaping characters.  But they were showing you how to do it using your typed string.  Since your values are coming from the $_POST you have to use the srt_replace to add the slashes along with the quote.

Comment: Seriously though, check out prepared statements.  Then these type of situations will be avoided.  Plus, you get the side bonus of better protection against malicious database attacks.

Comment: there is no query shown in the question so you cannot claim you know why its failing. all your conjectures about the junk of date being inserted are of no use

Comment: @Your Common Sense - For the sake of learning, am I wrong when it's stated that his query works with no quotes, but fails with quotes? My thinking was that If the query is not using prepared statements thus the quotes would have broken the query string when it was formed.  I see your point that assumptions were made and that there could be other logic that may have caused it to fail, but those options seem far more unlikely than what I suggested.  I suggested the prepared statements so no matter what data was presented it would not break a query string.  Again, I see your point about assumtion

Comment: he is using mysqli_real_escape_string so his query NEVER BLOODY FAILS, no matter what silly juggling with quotes were performed before. Either he is not using mysqli_real_escape_string, or his tales are not true at all. Either way you should have TESTED his improbable claims before trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` treats single quote as a string `END`. In order to `INSERT` string with single quotes you have to `ESCAPE` it as `\'Hello World\'`

This should work seamlessly

`$text_data = "hello my name is \'steve\'";`

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! but I have replaced single quotes with double quotes already

Comment: have u print what value u derived after converting your string?

Comment: replacing is one way to do this but not the best practice :-)

Comment: yes i did replace it and it prints out as expected: hello my name is "steve". with the double  quoting steve

Comment: Is this irrelevant to the question or misleading in any sense?